# How do I reset my Arduino Mega2560 with my C# application?

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino, reset

I noticed the Arduino IDE automatically resets on startup/exit by the built in serial application due to

> one of the hardware flow control lines (DTR) of the FT232RL is connected to the reset line of the ATmega1280 via a 100 nanofarad capacitor. When this line is asserted (taken low), the reset line drops long enough to reset the chip.

I noticed that behaviour does not happen with my serial C# application. I would like the reset feature to work with my C# application. What am I not doing to get my Arduino Mega to reset by my C# application?

**Working Code for Arduino and C#:**

I got it working in about 5 minutes by hooking up a wire from PWM Port12 to the RESET Port. On the Arduino, I checked for the text RESET on the incoming SerialEvent3. When RESET is found do:

```
pinMode(7, OUTPUT);  
digitalWrite(7, LOW);
```

As for as the C# it was as simple as:

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{ 
    serialPort1.Write("RESET"); 
}
```

Reset seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DTR works fine for me from the .NET SerialPort class.

Just set the property:

```
port.DtrEnable = true;
```

I have noticed different defaults if you use the SerialPort in the WinForms designer, but `DtrEnable` is in fact `true` (by default) when using it from a console app.

Comment: Wow, it was that easy!  Thank you.